# How to get access to blocked domains from a vps? (Monero mining pool URL)

Tags: dns, vps, mining

Mining pools supportxmr.com and minexmr.com are blocked by providers like vultr.com

```
miner@vultr_vps:~# ping pool.minexmr.com
ping: unknown host pool.minexmr.com
```

Hard coding IP addresses isn't possible, because multiple mining servers are setup with a round robin DNS behind the domain.

Any idea how I can access the pool anyway?

Comment: Hello, this question would better fit on superuser.com then stackoverflow, as it is more about configuration than code

Comment: Btw, you should focus on the generic problem (how to access an IP behind a round robin DNS) than your current situation (passing over Vultr policy)

Comment: Thanks for your advice. In the future I will consider that.

Comment: I mean, even now, if you formulate your question and title better, you will reach more people (I found this question just because I'm a reviewer)

Comment: All right but it looks like I found a solution. And the problem was the blocked domain, not the round robin DNS. I do not know how to rewrite a better question for this case ;/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this same issue today on Vultr. It's just a matter of not using their DNS servers (the example below uses the free DNS service offered by Google).

On Ubuntu 18.04 all you gotta do is open your DNS config for editing:

```
sudo nano /etc/resolv.conf
```

Then delete the entire contents of the file, and replace with:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a subdomain and setted up CNAME to pool.minexmr.com.

```
PING pool.minexmr.com (78.46.91.134) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from static.134.91.46.78.clients.your-server.de (78.46.91.134): icmp_seq=1 ttl=56 time=5.48 ms
```

It looks like everything is going to work well. The minexmr.com dashboard shows that the miner works correctly.